# Angular page builder / ui Builder

Tags: angular, user-interface, gui-designer

Edit: I have tried with "Form Array in Angular 9 to create the question with the type text,text area , checkbox, select box or add more videos and images into the survey. After that I will save all of them to database on the json format. At the end of processing, I will show the newest survey  for the customers, who is able to answer those questions."
sorry about my language. I have done with this question.

I am doing now a tool in order to create a list of questionnaires for the customers on the admin page by Angular 9 or 10.
In Angular, I have just seen only drag and drop at https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview. Howerver I would like to add images and video to the questionnaires.

I want to create a tool. In this tool, the admin can create the questionnaires and the customers could answer. Do you have an idea for that? because I do not know how to do it. and how to save this in the database system?

below it is my mission:
[image]

I researched but I did not find what is exactly. I just found some services for creating tool:
https://uibakery.io/
https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/drag-drop
https://stackblitz.com/github/IgniteUI/igniteui-live-editing-samples/tree/master/angular-demos/interactions/icons-sample?file=src%2Fapp%2Fdrag-drop%2Ficons-sample%2Ficons-sample.component.ts
https://techrev.us/platform/ui-designer
https://www.typeform.com/surveys/

Here is a sample on the admin page of Typeform:
[image]

Comment: Please, provide an example of what you have already tried and a concrete issue - currently there is not even a question asked here.

Comment: I want to create a tool. In this tool, the admin can create the questionnaires and the customers could answer. Do you have an idea for that? because I do not know how to do it. and how to save this in the database system?

Comment: I added more informaiton

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think there is no Angular library that fits your need (pls correct me when I´m wrong), that means you have to build the Frontend stuff on your own. Maybe you should start to learn how to design/create a database, how to create a Web API, and then learn how Angular JS works.

Comment: Last time I have already created a website with angular 9. Now I have to create this tool . then I do not have an idea for that, that is my challenge. That will be a little difficult to save all in the database. Because I am using now typescript + MySQL + Graphql for the backend

Comment: Maybe I must think more to find out a solution with angular. Thank you very much

Comment: the solution is here (I think)
https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: If you like Typeform product you can also directly use it and embed Typeform surveys into your app ;)

Comment: Thank everyone, I have to build this survey. I was using Form Array in angular to do this mission actualization.